# How to find volume generated by rotating the region

Tags: calculus

[image: diagram]

Referring to the figure above, find the volume generated by rotating the region R1 about the line OA.

I am so confused; what volume am I supposed to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula $V = \pi \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx$. In your example is $a=0,b=1$ and $f(x)=x^3$.
So $V = \pi \int_0^1 x^6 dx = \frac{\pi}{7}$

Comment: What happens when the line is about OC?

Comment: An easy form is just $\pi - \frac{1}{7}\pi$

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking for you to find the volume given by the blue region rotated about the x-axis. The blue region is the area under the curve y=x^3 from x=0 to x=1.

Comment: The integral of x^3 from 0 to 1 will give you the area of the region. However you should use [the washer method](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-applications-of-integration-new/ab-8-11/v/generalizing-the-washer-method) in order to calculate the volume.